# Angular i18n ignore / skip one element (i18n-ignore?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization

I have a couple elements I do not want to translate. Is there a way to tell my linter that some elements do not need translated?

I have reviewed this guide
https://angular.io/guide/i18n
And done a general google search

We don't want to translate these.

```
      <option value="en">
        English
      </option>
      <option value="es">
        Español
      </option>
```

Comment: why not use the pipeline of Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature  you wish it's not implemented yet but maybe in future we get some news about it. I recommend you create a request in [*Angular Github*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#feature).

---

My recomendation is follow in [*documentation of Pipes*](https://angular.io/api/common/I18nSelectPipe) you could create a pipe to put a translation u want maybe it could help you doing something like this:

```
@Component(
    {selector: 'i18n-select-pipe', template: `
        <option *ngFor="let o of optionsLanguage" >
            {{ o.value | i18nSelect: languageMap }}
        </option>
    `})
export class I18nSelectPipeComponent {
    optionsLanguage = [
        {id: "1", value: "en"},
        {id: "2", value: "es"}
    ];
    languageMap: any = {'en': 'English', 'es': 'Español'};
}
```

If its work I was glad to help you

:)